# How to find many results from an array with Lodash?

Tags: javascript, lodash

The following code loops thorugh an Object array, uses `_.find` to find the object of a certain category and push it into the `panoramaCats` array:

```
this.panoramas.forEach(panorama => {
  const panoramaCat = _.find(this.panoramas, { category: panorama.category })
  const panoramaCats = []
  panoramaCats.push(panoramaCat)
  payload[panorama.category] = panoramaCats
})
```

I thought `_.find` would find ALL the objects with that category, but it only finds the first one.

How to change the code so `_.find` finds ALL the object with that category?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [._matches](https://lodash.com/docs#matches) to find objects matching your criteria.

```
this.panoramas.forEach(panorama => {
  const panoramaCats = _.find(this.panoramas, _.matches({ category: panorama.category }))
  payload[panorama.category] = panoramaCats
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
this.panoramas.forEach(panorama => {
    payload[panorama.category] = _.find(this.panoramas, {category: panorama.category})
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using [_.groupBy](https://lodash.com/docs#groupBy)? I think it's simpler than manually looping through your collection.

```
payload = _.groupBy(this.panoramas, 'category')
```

If you need to preserve other pre-existing properties in your payload object you could use [_.merge](https://lodash.com/docs#merge):

```
payload = _.merge(payload, _.groupBy(this.panoramas, 'category'))
```